# Using gpg-agent to decrypt password in cron job

Tags: cron, gpg, gpg-agent

I have two scripts that both need to decrypt passwords using gpg-agent. Both of them run fine when launched from the terminal. The problem is that when run via cron, they both fail with these messages:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: End of file
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

I have this in `/etc/profile.d/gpg-agent.sh`:

```
if [ $EUID -ne 0 ] ; then
    envfile="$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env"
    if [[ -e "$envfile" ]] && kill -0 $(grep GPG_AGENT_INFO "$envfile" | cut -d: -f 2) 2>/dev/null; then
        eval "$(cat "$envfile")"
    else
        eval "$(gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file "$envfile")"
    fi
    export GPG_AGENT_INFO  # the env file does not contain the export statement
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK   # enable gpg-agent for ssh
fi
```

And I can verify the agent is running:

```
% pgrep gpg-agent
510
```

The cron tasks are in my own crontab. I've tried executing the scripts like this:

```
*/30 * * * * source /home/user/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env && export GPG_AGENT_INFO && /script
```

But nothing I've tried works.

Comment: Is the agent running when your crontab runs? It's only started when you log in (and depending on your configuration, it might get killed when you log out). If you run `env -i HOME="$HOME" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin/sh LOGNAME="$LOGNAME" USER="$USER" 'source /home/user/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env && export GPG_AGENT_INFO && /script'`, does it work?

Comment: The single quote syntax isn't working. I get `env: source /home/user/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env && export GPG_AGENT_INFO && /script: No such file or directory`. I also tried `env - HOME="$HOME" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin/sh LOGNAME="$LOGNAME" USER="$USER" $(source /home/user/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env && export GPG_AGENT_INFO)` but the GPG_AGENT_INFO isn't present.

Comment: Sorry, I left out a part, it should be env -i HOME="$HOME" PATH=/usr/bin:/bin SHELL=/bin/sh LOGNAME="$LOGNAME" USER="$USER" sh -c 'source /home/user/.gnupg/gpg-agent.env && export GPG_AGENT_INFO && /script' (with the real path for `/script` of course).

Comment: That works, but the script still doesn't work. If I change the script at the end to `echo $GPG_AGENT_INFO` then I do see the correct path and pid for gpg-agent. So something's still wrong with my gpg setup. I have `use-agent` in my `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`. I also have `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses` in my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn't work”, do you mean that this `env -i …` prints the “gpg: problem with the agent: End of file” message? If so, it means that gpg needs another variable that is usually in your environment.

Comment: Yes, exactly. How would I go about identifying which variable it is that I need? The only gpg-related variable I see in my `env` is `GPG_AGENT_INFO`.